# Using Jquery click function, executes code in some places but not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I might have missed something obvious here, apologies in advance if so...

Using ajax-solr and implementing my own version of their Current Search widget example/tutorial - https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial%3A-step-5 I have a code snippet which looks like this:

```
(function($) {
   AjaxSolr.CurrentSearchWidget = AjaxSolr.AbstractWidget.extend({
      start: 0,

      afterRequest: function() {
         var self = this;
         var links = [];

         var q = self.manager.store.get('q').val();
         var qText = q;
         if (q != null && q != '*:*') {
            if (q.split(':').length == 2) {
               qText = q.split(':')[1];
            }
            links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                       .text('search: ' + qText + ' (remove)').click(function() {
               localStorage.removeItem("query");
               localStorage.setItem("query", "*");
               self.manager.store.get('q').val('*:*');
               self.doRequest();
               return false;
            }));
         }

         var fq = self.manager.store.values('fq');
         var prettyText = "";
         for (var i = 0, l = fq.length; i < l; i++) {
              //string manipulation for user-facing text
              links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                         .text(prettyText + ' (remove)').click(self.removeFacet(fq[i])));

             //local storage stuff
           }
           if (links.length > 1) {
              links.unshift($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                            .text('remove all').click(function() {
                 localStorage.clear();
                 localStorage.setItem("query", "*");
                 self.manager.store.get('q').val('*');
                 self.manager.store.remove('fq');
                 self.doRequest();
                 return false;
              }));
           }

           //update DOM
        },
```

I've stripped out the unecessary code, but the above works fine. However, if I change

```
links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                             .text(prettyText + ' (remove)')
                             .click(self.removeFacet(fq[i])));
```

to use a function as per the examples above it and below, like

```
links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                             .text(prettyText + ' (remove)')
                             .click(function () {
   self.removeFacet(fq[i]);
}));
```

so that I can add additional code there, it no longer runs removeFacet when the anchor is clicked. Thanks for any help on what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with function scope. This is not pointing to your object anymore. I would suggest binding your "self" object like so.

```
links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
        .text(prettyText + ' (remove)')
        .click(function () {
            var self = this;
            self.removeFacet(fq[i]);
         }).bind(self));
```

Comment: A scope issue makes perfect sense, but unfortunately I can't seem to make your changes work, I just keep getting a jQuery "TypeError: m.push is not a function" which I can't seem to fix

Answer (score 0):

please see if changing to this works

```
links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
                             .text(prettyText + ' (remove)')
                             .on('click', function () {
   self.removeFacet(fq[i]);
}));
```

Comment: That makes no difference unfortunately, as others have said it looks like a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ran into - you have inner functions (the anonymous click function) that is not executed immediately, therefore the iterator gets "lost". Taking the following example

```
var i, colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];

for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var color = colors[i];
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(color);
    }, i * 1000);
}
// red, red, red
```

would log 3 times red, because the code of the function (here inside the timeout) is executed outside the loop, the iterator is at its last position.

Using this variant the value would be captured at each iteration into an argument to a function, which does create a scope, which would produce
the output green, blue, and red

```
var i, colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];

for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    (function(color) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(color);
        }, i * 1000);
    })(colors[i]);
}
// green, blue, red
```

In your case something like this should work:

```
links.push($('<a href="#" class="cur-search"></a>')
.text(prettyText + ' (remove)')
.click((function(instance, facet) {
    // your code here
    // and delete
    instance.removeFacet(facet);
})(self, fq[i]));
```

Comment: A scope issue makes sense, but I've tried your changes and removeFacet is still not called unfortunately.

Comment: @KirstyB. can you confirm that it is not called, or is it called with an incorrect element? Do you get any js error?

Comment: It's not called at all, and there are no console errors

Comment: @KirstyB. when you dump instance and facet, do you get objects? And is the click method itself executed? Can you provide a kind of working code to look at?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use the **on** function. Try something like this...

```
$(window, "a.cur-search", function () {
        var self = this;
        self.removeFacet(fq[i]);
     });
```

You might need to put fq[i] in **data** or something to make it available.